# Css button doesn't respond when hovered over

Tags: html, css, positioning, opacity, overlapping

So I had the button working until i added a new block div called 'dark-blueright' and positioned it under 'light-blue'.

```css
/*
▒█▀▀▀█ ▀▀█▀▀ ▒█░░▒█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ▒█▀▀█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▒█▀▀▀█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▀▀█▀▀ 
░▀▀▀▄▄ ░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ▒█▄▄▀ ▒█▀▀▀ ░▀▀▀▄▄ ▒█▀▀▀ ░▒█░░ 
▒█▄▄▄█ ░▒█░░ ░░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄█ ▒█▄▄▄ 　 ▒█░▒█ ▒█▄▄▄ ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█▄▄▄ ░▒█░░ 

*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
▒█▀▀▀█ ▀▀█▀▀ ▒█░░▒█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ▒█▀▀▀█ ▒█░▒█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▒█▀▀▀ ▀▀█▀▀ 
░▀▀▀▄▄ ░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ░▀▀▀▄▄ ▒█▀▀█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▒█▀▀▀ ░▒█░░ 
▒█▄▄▄█ ░▒█░░ ░░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄█ ▒█▄▄▄ 　 ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█░▒█ ▒█▄▄▄ ▒█▄▄▄ ░▒█░░ 
*/

@font-face {
 font-family: headingf;
 src: url(header-font.ttf); 
}
@font-face {
 font-family: mainf;
 src: url(main-font.ttf); 
}
@font-face {
 font-family: iconf;
 src: url(icon.ttf); 
}
.background_colour {
 background-color: #c6cdd1;
 height: 1700px;
 position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
 z-index: -2;
}
.iconsf {
 font-family: iconf;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-indent: 40px;
 float: left;
}
.light-blue {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #68cef3;
}
.dark-blueright {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #00aae7;
 position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
 
}
.header-text {
 font-family: headingf;
 font-size: 170px;
 position: inherit;
 text-align: center;
 top: 80px;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 10px 
}
.welcome-text {
 font-family: mainf;
 font-size: 70px;
 position: inherit;
 text-align: center;
 top: 60px;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 10px 
}
.button-style1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 220px;
 left: 400px;
 background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #00a9e7), color-stop(1, #00a9e7) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #00a9e7 5%, #00a9e7 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00a9e7', endColorstr='#00a9e7');
 background-color:#00a9e7;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
 border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
 border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 text-indent:-20px;
 border:1px solid #ffffff;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:mainf;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-style:normal;
 height:80px;
 line-height:80px;
 width:200px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
}
.button-style1:hover {
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.button-style1:active {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
 <div class="background_colour">
 <div class="dark-blueright">
 </div>
  <div class="light-blue">
   <div class="header-text">
   Oh. Hello
   </div>
   <div class="welcome-text">
   welcome
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="button-style1"><span class="iconsf">r</span>Goto art</a>
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted the button to change opacity when hovered, which it did. But my positioning skills in css are awful and couldn't find help researching.

Comment: then what is the question?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Is the problem with  opacity when you hover, or with positioning? Also there seems to be a lot more code in your question than is likely to be relevant to the question. It would really help to reduce it to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the question is, how do i make the buttons hover function work. it's broken from the positioning of 'dark-blueright'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your z-index on class **.background_colour** was wrong, I corrected that and the hover effect is working now.

```css
/*
▒█▀▀▀█ ▀▀█▀▀ ▒█░░▒█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ▒█▀▀█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▒█▀▀▀█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▀▀█▀▀ 
░▀▀▀▄▄ ░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ▒█▄▄▀ ▒█▀▀▀ ░▀▀▀▄▄ ▒█▀▀▀ ░▒█░░ 
▒█▄▄▄█ ░▒█░░ ░░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄█ ▒█▄▄▄ 　 ▒█░▒█ ▒█▄▄▄ ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█▄▄▄ ░▒█░░ 

*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
▒█▀▀▀█ ▀▀█▀▀ ▒█░░▒█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ▒█▀▀▀█ ▒█░▒█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▒█▀▀▀ ▀▀█▀▀ 
░▀▀▀▄▄ ░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▀▀▀ 　 ░▀▀▀▄▄ ▒█▀▀█ ▒█▀▀▀ ▒█▀▀▀ ░▒█░░ 
▒█▄▄▄█ ░▒█░░ ░░▒█░░ ▒█▄▄█ ▒█▄▄▄ 　 ▒█▄▄▄█ ▒█░▒█ ▒█▄▄▄ ▒█▄▄▄ ░▒█░░ 
*/

@font-face {
 font-family: headingf;
 src: url(header-font.ttf); 
}
@font-face {
 font-family: mainf;
 src: url(main-font.ttf); 
}
@font-face {
 font-family: iconf;
 src: url(icon.ttf); 
}
.background_colour {
 background-color: #c6cdd1;
 height: 1700px;
 position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
 z-index: 0;
}
.iconsf {
 font-family: iconf;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-indent: 40px;
 float: left;
}
.light-blue {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #68cef3;
}
.dark-blueright {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #00aae7;
 position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
 
}
.header-text {
 font-family: headingf;
 font-size: 170px;
 position: inherit;
 text-align: center;
 top: 80px;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 10px 
}
.welcome-text {
 font-family: mainf;
 font-size: 70px;
 position: inherit;
 text-align: center;
 top: 60px;
 color: #ffffff;
 letter-spacing: 10px 
}
.button-style1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 220px;
 left: 400px;
 background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #00a9e7), color-stop(1, #00a9e7) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #00a9e7 5%, #00a9e7 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00a9e7', endColorstr='#00a9e7');
 background-color:#00a9e7;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
 border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
 border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 text-indent:-20px;
 border:1px solid #ffffff;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:mainf;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-style:normal;
 height:80px;
 line-height:80px;
 width:200px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
}
.button-style1:hover {
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.button-style1:active {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
 <div class="background_colour">
 <div class="dark-blueright">
 </div>
  <div class="light-blue">
   <div class="header-text">
   Oh. Hello
   </div>
   <div class="welcome-text">
   welcome
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="button-style1"><span class="iconsf">r</span>Goto art</a>
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```